# Is it possible to block a PowerShell module from running on anything less than Windows 8?

Tags: powershell

I've written many modules but have come across a case where I want to block my module from running on operating systems lower than Win8. I realize I can write a function to check `Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem`, however I'm curious if the **module manifest** has any 'tricks' to block certain OS versions?

Comment: While you can't target an OS version specifically what do you require that is only present on Windows 8 and later? There are other options such as PowerShell version, .NET version, required .NET assemblies, etc. that you might be able to use.

Comment: I have a large module which takes advantage of modules not included in Windows 7 (i.e. ScheduledTasks, Windows Location Services components, and other bits).

Comment: In that case I recommend making using the `RequiredModules = @()` element in the module manifest. More at this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/developer/module/how-to-write-a-powershell-module-manifest

Comment: Sorry but that area in the article doesn't apply to this situation. Thanks though.

Comment: I'm confused. The linked article shows how the `RequiredModules = @()` element can be used along with other options to restrict where a module can be run. Can you expand on what doesn't apply?

Comment: Certainly. That element refers to modules which your module would depend on. It has no application to the selection of an operating system. Perhaps if you feel this is incorrect, you could provide an example where this element could be used to restrict the OS version as per my question.

Comment: Of course! Since there are not any elements in the manifest file that allow you to specify what OSes the module should run under you'll have to be indirect about it. I may not have been clear before but the easiest method to do this is restrict them module to run only when a module is both present and above a certain version and even GUID, if desired. e.g. `RequiredModules = @(@{ModuleName="myDependentModule", RequiredVersion="1.5",Guid="cfc45206-1e49-459d-a8ad-5b571ef94857"})` using this you can find what identifiers will restrict the module from running on OSes lower than Windows 8.

Comment: Perhaps you can give an answer then and illustrate exactly how you would use this parameter to restrict certain operating system versions.